# Conversion to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, formal-languages, chomsky-normal-form

I do need your help.
I have these productions:

```
1) A--> aAb
2) A--> bAa
3) A--> ε
```

I should apply the Chomsky Normal Form (CNF).

In order to apply the above rule I should:

1. eliminate ε producions
2. eliminate unitary productions
3. remove useless symbols

Immediately I get stuck. The reason is that A is a nullable symbol (ε is part of its body)

Of course I can't remove the A symbol.

Can anyone help me to get the final solution?

Answer (score 2):

As the [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) notes, there are two definitions of Chomsky Normal Form, which differ in the treatment of ε productions. You will have to pick the one where these are allowed, as otherwise you will never get an equivalent grammar: your grammar produces the empty string, while a CNF grammar following the other definition isn't capable of that.

Comment: So actually you're saying that my reasoning is completely wrong? What should I do?....

Comment: @Joachim: I'm saying you should read the definitions over at Wikipedia closely and decide if you want a completely equivalent grammar or not.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. Since ε is a member of the language of the grammar, clearly the first definition applies. The OPs problem can be solved by making the grammar essentially noncontracting, then removing chain rules and useless symbols.

Comment: @danportin: that wasn't my clearest comment ever. Sometimes, it suffices to define a non-equivalent grammar that always generates an extra symbol and prepend/append that symbol to the input before running the CKY algorithm.

Comment: That makes sense, and sounds practical. But for the purpose of the exercise, which presumably is to ensure that the OP understands and can execute the algorithms correctly, the first option is more prudent.

Answer (score 2):

To begin conversion to Chomsky normal form (using Definition (1) provided by the Wikipedia page), you need to find an equivalent essentially noncontracting grammar. A grammar `G` with start symbol `S` is essentially noncontracting iff

```
1. S is not a recursive variable
2. G has no ε-rules other than S -> ε if ε ∈ L(G)
```

Calling your grammar `G`, an equivalent grammar `G'` with a non-recursive start symbol is:

```
G' : S -> A
     A -> aAb | bAa | ε
```

Clearly, the set of nullable variables of `G'` is `{S,A}`, since `A -> ε` is a production in `G'` and `S -> A` is a chain rule. I assume that you have been given an algorithm for removing ε-rules from a grammar. That algorithm should produce a grammar similar to:

```
G'' : S -> A | ε
      A -> aAb | bAa | ab | ba
```

The grammar `G''` is essentially noncontracting; you can now apply the remaining algorithms to the grammar to find an equivalent grammar in Chomsky normal form.

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation. Unfortunately I still have problems solving the exercise. I'm a student and since in a few days time I'm going to take an examination (Programming language and Compilers)...I'm wondering if I can rely on someone knowledge in order to fill my gaps...This is my email address: moose_2009@operamail.com Thank you

Comment: If you attempt to solve the problem first and accept answers, you will probably find the members of SO to be knowledgeable and helpful.